# From a partition to a surjective function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ a $Y$ be two sets. It is easy to show that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a surjective function (thus the partition is definitely not empty) then it defines a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $X$. I would like to know if the vece versa is true and that is if a partition $\mathcal{P}$ induces a surjective function $f\colon X\to Y$ and in case of answer affirmative I would like to know how such a function is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed!

To be clear, by a **partition** here, we must mean a collection $ \mathcal P $ of subsets of $ X $ that are all inhabited (non-empty), so that every element of $ \mathcal P $ has at least one element of $ X $ in it, and also mutually disjoint and exhaustive, so that every element of $ X $ is in one and only one element of $ \mathcal P $.  Then you can take $ \mathcal P $ *itself* to be the set $ Y $ and define a function $ f $ from $ X $ to $ Y $ so that each element of $ X $ is mapped to the element of $ \mathcal P $ that it belongs to.

More generally, if $ \mathcal P $ is a collection of subsets of $ X $ that are still mutually disjoint and exhaustive, but which are *not* required to be inhabited, then we can still take $ \mathcal P $ to be $ Y $ and define a function $ f $ from $ X $ to $ Y $ as before.  But now $ f $ may not be surjective; in fact, $ f $ will be surjective if and only if every element of $ \mathcal P $ is inhabited (so that $ \mathcal P $ is a partition) after all.  (This is kind of a trivial extension, since the only way that $ \mathcal P $ can fail to be a partition is if $ \varnothing \in \mathcal P $, in which case $ \mathcal P \setminus \{ \varnothing \} $ is a partition, but at least we have options.  You can get more variety by allowing the elements of $ \mathcal P $ to be things *other* than subsets of $ X $, although arguably that violates the spirit of the situation.)

Also, $ f $ will be injective if and only if every element of $ \mathcal P $ has at *most* one element of $ X $ in it.  (So $ f $ will be bijective if and only if every element of $ \mathcal { P } $ is a singleton; then $ f ( a ) = \{ a \} $ for each element $ a $ of $ X $.)